# Does Mortgage Forbearance affect future refinances?

Tags: mortgage, credit-history, debt-restructuring, covid-19

Assuming my credit score is unaffected, if I were to apply for the mortgage forbearance for people affected by the coronavirus, and then later (say 1 year after the forbearance period is over), if I were to apply for a refinance through the same lender, would they include that forbearance as a factor when determining my rate and/or approval?

Since it were through the same lender, they'd know about the forbearance even without it being on my credit report, so would there be worse chances of refinancing with this lender than at others?

Comment: You usually have to pay all you owe at some point. Forbearance doesn't mean that you don't owe the money. It's just been delayed for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what lender you apply to, your credit report will show that you applied for forbearance.

The lenders won't really take into account the forbearance. What they will take into account is your credit report.

Don't use the forbearance period as a get rich scheme otherwise your credit report will be horrible.

In conclusion, no forbearance will not affect refinance, but the impact of forbearance to your credit score will

Comment: I'm not planning to use it as a get rich quick scheme or anything like that for that matter; I may end up needing to take a forbearance period due to the coronavirus, however I have a 15 year mortgage and I may later want to refinance to a 30 year mortgage to reduce the monthly payment and was curious about whether taking a forbearance to put off payments in the event i lost my job would cause issues if i tried refinancing to a longer term later on